# WxWidgets using wxString

Tags: wxwidgets, calculator, wxstring

I'm taking a computer sciences class and we have to make a calculator using a GUI. I have been banging my head into a wall trying to even get input though.
Understand how to use pointers and GetValue(), to take in the input as a wxString but that does me no good, If I can't get the string as a double or integer then I can't perform operations on it. 
Does anyone know how to convert wxString to Double? or even int?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, there are the two functions ToDouble and ToLong.
For details take a look at the offical documentation:
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxstring.html#wxstringtolong
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxstring.html#wxstringtodouble

EDIT: Example:

```
wxTextCtrl ctrl;
// user has entered a number
double number;
if( !ctrl.GetValue().ToDouble( &number ) )
    // handle error
else
    // continue...
```

Please note: It will only work if you enter a number. If you enter a term like *2+3* the function should return false. In this case you have to split the string up and interpret all numbers seperately.

Comment: I have already taken a look at those resources, but I can't usethem without govng me an error, could you please type out a little example of how the function works?